# Why am I getting 404 error from Express Route when the route exists?

Tags: angular, express, post, routes

Trying to accomplish the most basic POST possible while using express and cannot figure out why I am getting a 404 error when the route exists.

**angular/express/server.js**

```js
const express = require('express');
var app = express();
const http = require('http');
const path = require('path');
const passport = require('passport');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const session = require('express-session');
const errorhandler = require('errorhandler');
var cors = require('cors')

var env = process.env.NODE_ENV || 'development';

const config = require('./config/config')[env];

console.log('Using configuration', config);

require('./config/passport')(passport, config);


app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(session(
  {
    resave: true,
    saveUninitialized: true,
    cookieName: 'session',
    secret: 'random_string_goes_here',
    duration: 15 ,
    activeDuration: 15,
    maxAge: 30
  }));
app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());
app.use(morgan('combined'));
app.use(cors());
app.options('*', cors());

app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,POST,OPTIONS,DELETE,PUT');
  res.setHeader('Access-Control-Allow-Credentials', true);
  next();
}); 
 

app.set('port', config.app.port);



require('./config/routes')(app, config, passport);


app.listen(app.get('port'), function () {
  console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
```

**angular/express/config/routes.js**

```js
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()
var app = express()
var xmldoc = require('xmldoc');
var DOMParser = require('dom-parser');
//const cors = require("cors"); 
//const corsOptions = { origin: "*", credentials: true }; 
//app.use(cors(corsOptions)); 

  app.post('/nameid',  function (req, res) {
    nameid = ({ 'nameid': 'hi'});
console.log(nameid);
console.log(JSON.stringify(nameid));
   res.send(JSON.stringify(nameid));
      })


module.exports = function (app, config, passport) {
 
   app.post('/nameid',  function (req, res) {
    nameid = ({ 'nameid': 'hi2'});
console.log(nameid);
console.log(JSON.stringify(nameid));
   res.send(JSON.stringify(nameid));
      })

  app.get('/', function (req, res) {
      res.redirect('/home')
  });


  app.post('/', function(req, res) {

  
   
        app.post('/nameid2',  function (req, res) {
    nameid = ({ 'nameid': 'hi'});
console.log(nameid);
console.log(JSON.stringify(nameid));
   res.send(JSON.stringify(nameid));
      })

  

});
};
```

Note I have a route for nameid and nameid2 so I could test two seperate ways at a time when I committed my changes. I am trying to just get one of these to work in any way possible.

Below is the code calling the POST from Angular:

**angular/src/app/service.services.ts**

```js
    getNameID(): Observable<NameIDResult[]> {
    const url = environment.apiUrl+'nameid';
     const data = ({

    });
    return this._http.post(url, data)
    .pipe(
      map((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return <NameIDResult[]> res;
      })
    );
  }
  
      getNameID2(): Observable<NameIDResult[]> {
    const url = environment.apiUrl+'nameid2';
     const data = ({

    });
    return this._http.post(url, data)
    .pipe(
      map((res) => {
        console.log(res);
        return <NameIDResult[]> res;
      })
    );
  }
```

Any advice would be truly appreciated as I have tried everything I can think of.

Current errors:

```js
ERROR 
Object { headers: {…}, status: 404, statusText: "Not Found", url: "https://example.com/nameid2", ok: false, name: "HttpErrorResponse", message: "Http failure response for https://example.com/nameid2: 404 Not Found", error: "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title></title><link rel=\"stylesheet\" href=\"/stylesheets/style.css\"></head><body><h1>Not Found</h1><h2>404</h2><pre>Error: Not Found\n    at /usr/src/app/app.js:51:15\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)\n    at trim_prefix (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)\n    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:284:7\n    at Function.process_params (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)\n    at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)\n    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:635:15\n    at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:260:14)\n    at next (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:127:14)\n    at cors (/usr/src/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:188:7)\n    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:224:17\n    at originCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:214:15)\n    at /usr/src/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:219:13\n    at optionsCallback (/usr/src/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:199:9)\n    at corsMiddleware (/usr/src/app/node_modules/cors/lib/index.js:204:7)\n    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/usr/src/app/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)</pre></body></html>" }
```

Comment: You web request is sent to `https://example.org/`, which I'm guessing is wrong

Comment: I put that in as an example -- the request goes to the correct url.

Comment: show me your complete Request Url, which is on network tab

Comment: The request URL resolves to (note https:// does not show in link)

    https://mywebsitesname.com/nameid

It has a method of POST and it is coming back with a 404 error.

Comment: Did your `routes.js` content copy over correctly here?  It seems... malformed? I.e., why do you have an `app.post('/', function ...` surrounding both the `router.post('/nameid'...` and `app.post('/nameid2'...)` blocks?
And what is the ending `};` supposed to be closing?

Comment: okay bro let me know that your console value showing on cmd or no? if not consoling then the problem with your server configuration

Comment: I added the entire console error to the main post.

Comment: @GreggL -- you are correct my routes.js did get messed up some how. I updated.

Answer (score 0):

Somewhere inside `angular/express/server.js` you need to tell it explicitly that you want to use the routes from `angular/express/config/routes.js`.  First import your `routes.js`:

```
const routes = require('/path/to/routes.js');
```

then at the right place among your app.use statements insert this:

```
app.use('/', routes);
```

Note: I would suggest giving some sort of subdomain for your api such as this:

```
app.use('/api/v1', routes);
```